# Configuring nginx to work with multiple PHP front controllers

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I'm currently trying to migrate a PHP app that is in the middle of being converted from php file per page to a front controller based system, from a server running Apache to Nginx. The site has a couple of other PHP apps in sub folders that use their own front controllers, but keep running into iossues with try_files either not working for some of the old urls to files that no longer exist or the root try_files overwriting the sub folder try_files.

For example:

Requests for /section.php/123/1/slugtext should get sent to PHP as /front.php/section.php/123/1/slugtext

Requests for /en/section/123/1/slugtext should get sent to PHP as /front.php/en/section/123/1/slugtext

Requests for /admin/api/Ping should get sent to PHP as /admin/admin_api.php/Ping

Any requests under /news/ should get sent to PHP as /news/index.php

Of course these rewrites should only happen for non existent files/directories.

Config:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $is_https{
    https on;
}

server {
        listen ip:80;
        server_name mydomain.tld;

        return  301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen ip:80;

    root /home/www/mydomain/shop/htdocs;

    server_name www.mydomain.tld;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    rewrite ^(.*)\.v[\d]+\.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ $1.$2;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {log_not_found off;access_log off;}
    location = /robots.txt {allow all;log_not_found off;access_log off;}
    location ~ /\. {deny all;}

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /front.php$uri;
    }

    location ~ ^/admin/api(.*) {
            try_files $1 $1/ /admin/admin_api.php$1;
    }    

    location ^~ /news {
        alias /home/www/mydomain/wordpress/htdocs;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /news/news/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-wordpress.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE default_charset=UTF-8;
                location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {deny all;}
            }
        location ~ /\. {deny all;}
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $is_https if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE default_charset=ISO-8859-1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-shop.sock;
    }
}
```

This config is the closest I've got to working but when I make requests for /section.php, which doesn't exist anymore and the front controller should handle and generate a 301 to the new URL, it seems Nginx ignores the the try_files in the / location block (I guess because the PHP one is a better match), if I move the try_files directly into the server block it works the same, if I add it to the PHP block it overrides the /admin/api one and all API requests get routed to front.php.

I'd got this working in Apache using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/bbapi/(.*)$ /admin/admin_api.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /front.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
location = /section.php {
    try_files /front.php$uri =404;
}
```

It will make sure that the `section.php` is passed as-is to `front.php`.

Comment: `try_files` requires 2 parameters, so make sure you pass a file to attempt before your fallback.

Comment: That is so true, I updated the answer.